# Variable scopes in coderefs if perl, need an explanation of strange behavior

Tags: perl, variables, scope

Why are the values of $copy_of_i's returned by coderefs in the @coderefs the same?

```
use Modern::Perl;
my @coderefs = ();
for (my $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    push @coderefs, sub { 
        my $copy_of_i = $i;
        return $copy_of_i;
    };
}

say $coderefs[1]->();
say $coderefs[3]->();
```

I thought the $copy_of_i would be local for every coderef added to @coderefs and thus contain the current value of $i assigned to the $copy_of_i at the given iteration of the loop. But if we display the values of a couple of $copi_of_i's with 'say' we'll see that they have the same values as if the $copy_of_i wasn't local for every newly created coderef. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to have different values associated with the closures, yet you only have the single variable `$i` for all the closures to capture. You need to create a variable for each closure to capture, so `$copy_of_i` should be created outside of the closure. Creating a copy when you call the closure is far too late; `$i` no longer contains the desired value at that point.

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    my $copy_of_i = $i;
    push @coderefs, sub { 
      return $copy_of_i;
    };
}
```

By the way, `for my $i (0 .. 5)` is preferred over `for (my $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)`, and it has the advantage of creating a new variable for each iteration of the loop, so you can simply use

```
my @coderefs;
for my $i (0 .. 4) {
    push @coderefs, sub { 
      return $i;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Сухой27! This works. But I still don't get the mechanics of the process. Could you explain why my code doesn't work. What happens when I declare the $copy_of_i within the body of the coderef and why I should delcare the variable outside of it instead?

Comment: @Tyoma check update and memory addresses for `$i` variable https://eval.in/240135 (same) https://eval.in/240136 (differ)

Comment: The equivalent to the for loop in the question would actually be `for my $i (0 .. 4)`.

Comment: @nwellnhof tnx for comment.